# Lifting foldr to monad

Tags: haskell, monads, fold

I have function `smallStep :: Command -> Data -> Either StepError Data`, and I would like to make `bigStep :: [Command] -> Data -> Either StepError Data` using it, with following semantic:

```
bigStep []   data   = Right data
bigStep c:cs data   = do
               data' <- bigStep cs data
               smallStep c data'
```

It's nothing convoluted, but if `smallStep` had type `Command -> Data -> Data`, I would implement `bigStep` simply as `bigStep commands data = foldr data smallStep commands`.

Naturally, I would like to use `foldr` here as well. How do I do this? `foldM` is lifted `foldl`, and reversing list doesn't sound like a terribly good idea.

Comment: The last line should be `smallStep c data'`, shouldn't it? Problem: what if some later `smallStep` fails? If that can't happen, the type is wrong. If it can fail, and you don't want to turn that failure into a pattern-match error, your options are, as far as I see, what you have, or reversing and `foldM`. Reversing might actually be better, since `bigStep (c:cs) d = bigStep cs d >>= smallStep c` may build a bigger thunk.

Comment: You can still use `foldr`.  You just need to give it an appropriate reducer function: `(a -> b -> b) = (Data -> E Command -> E Command)` (where `E = Either StepError`).  You have a `(Data -> Command -> E Command)`.  So how do you *extend* a function of type `a -> E b` to one of type `E a -> E b`?   Hint: it's one of the fundamental operations of a monad.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't think I understood you. If `smallStep` couldn't fail, `bigStep` would be just a `foldr`. But it can, so I have to dance around `Either` monad.

Comment: `bigStep cs d = foldr ((=<<) . smallStep) (return d) cs`

Answer (score 8):

In general, a left fold won't be better or worse than a right fold in terms of resource usage. However, I would assume that `[Command]` is supposed to be a list of *sequenced* commands intended to be executed one after another in the order they are supplied. If that is the case, it is probably easiest to build these lists backwards to begin with (instead of reversing them - this is indeed a costly operation for long lists). If you don't want to do that, here is a general monadic right fold:

```
foldrM :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m b) -> b -> [a] -> m b
foldrM f d []     = return d
foldrM f d (x:xs) = (\z -> f x z) =<< foldrM f d xs
```

Note the types of all the following :

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldM :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a

foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldrM :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m b) -> b -> [a] -> m b
```

We can deduce that `foldrM` is indeed a right fold.

However, if you need to `fold` a very large list, both of the monadic folds above are lazy and will only begin evaluation once the last function application is sequenced.